# "Facebook CDN not allowed for og:image" when sharing a Facebook post on Facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph, facebook-ios-sdk, meta

I have an app that pulls posts from liked Facebook groups, and allows users to share them. In order to get the correct thumbnail on the shared post, I have used the `og:image` meta tag when sharing. The image in the `og:image` tag is from the original Facebook post, which means it's located at `https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/`. When I share the post on Facebook, the image is not displayed, and upon checking in the Object Debugger, I found out that Facebook has somehow disallowed sharing their own images on their own platform using the og tags. Here is the error:
[image: Facebook CDN not allowed for og:image]

Is there some sort of workaround, or a different way to share images located at Facebook CDN using the og:image tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no workaround, you should never use the CDN links or rely on them. They're set to expire after some time for example so the link could become invalid. You could however download the image and then host it yourself.